# Does it matter which way the columns and rows go in R?

Tags: r

so I imported some large datasets from the Cancer Dependency Map.

In particular I have two datasets that consist of 17,000+ gene knockout scores in around 600 cancer cell lines. (So for every gene there are 600 scores)

The way the two datasets are formatted are very different however. In the first dataset there are 600 observations of 17,000+ variables whereas the second dataset is the other way around with 17,000+ variables of 600 observations.

Is there a correct guideline for formatting the columns and rows of the datasets? I have to transpose one of them to match the other but I don't know which way to do it.

600x17,000 or 17,000x600?

Comment: I think you want to read [Tidy Data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: Please add a reproducible example (17 x 6 dataset is enough) and example of wanted output

Comment: Also depends on what you want to do.  You may be able to use the `apply` function on each data set and just change the dimension number.  i.e. operating on the rows `apply(df, 1, func)` or the columns `apply(df, 2, func)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This often happens with Bioinformatics Data and there is no universal "standard" way of storing the data like this.
Depending on the analysis you want to perform you need to select either gene scores to be your "observations" or cancer cells.
Are you going to access your dataset for each cell line or a gene score?
I would suggest to store your dataset in a matrix format rather than as a data.frame. Then accessing rows and columns of your dataset will be faster.
If you decide to use a data.frame format, then it will be more efficient to have fewer columns ( 600 in your case ).

Here are a few time measurements to consider  when you access the data stored in a matrix or a data.frame format:

```
library(microbenchmark)

m.long <- matrix (rnorm(17000 * 600 ), ncol=600 )
m.wide <- t(m.long)

dt.long <- as.data.frame(m.long)
dt.wide <- as.data.frame(m.wide)

microbenchmark(
  m.long[, 100], m.long[100,],
  m.wide[, 100 ], m.wide[100,],
  dt.long[, 100], dt.long[100,],
  dt.wide[, 100 ], dt.wide[100,] )


# Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
#  m.long[, 100]     48.7     54.80     59.017     57.80     62.20    102.3   100
#  m.long[100, ]      7.6     26.05     37.982     42.00     47.95     97.9   100
#  m.wide[, 100]      3.2      5.70      8.437      7.65      9.75     23.1   100
#  m.wide[100, ]    196.9    644.25    604.437    702.25    719.55   1197.6   100
# dt.long[, 100]     13.9     19.20     28.599     26.50     35.15     82.6   100
# dt.long[100, ]   5344.6   5748.75   6369.545   5884.00   6113.65  14295.8   100
# dt.wide[, 100]     30.6     40.00     51.182     50.60     61.25     92.7   100
# dt.wide[100, ] 156880.1 171868.80 180059.101 177808.10 184051.20 279418.9   100
```

As you can see the time to access rows and columns greatly differs depending on the format you store your data.

So in your case it all depends what you plan to do with your data, which functions you plan to apply to them and what those functions expect as an input.